# Visualization of Napoleon's theorem with Tkz-euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

Here is a [short Wikipedia Definition of Napoleon's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon%27s_theorem):

> "Napoleon's theorem states that if equilateral triangles are
> constructed on the sides of any triangle, either all outward or all
> inward, the lines connecting the centres of those equilateral
> triangles themselves form an equilateral triangle."

I tried to visualize this in tkz-euclide, but it doesn't work for me. MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){a}
\tkzDefPoint(5,1){b}
\tkzDefPoint(1,4){c}
\tkzDefPoint(1,-3){d}
\tkzDefPoint(6,4){e}
\tkzDefPoint(-1,3){f}

\tkzDrawPolygon(a,b,c)
\tkzDrawPolygon(a,b,d)
\tkzDrawPolygon(b,c,e)
\tkzDrawPolygon(a,c,f)

\tkzInCenter(a,b,c)\tkzGetPoint{D}

\tkzInCenter(a,b,d)\tkzGetPoint(A)

\tkzInCenter(b,c,e)\tkzGetPoint(B)

\tkzInCenter(a,c,f)\tkzGetPoint(C)

\tkzDrawPoint[red](D)
\tkzDrawPoint[red](A)
\tkzDrawPoint[red](B)
\tkzDrawPoint[red](C)
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C) 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I geht the following error messages: `No shape named 'A' is known.`, `No shape named 'B' is known.`, `No shape named 'C' is known.` which is weird, since it apparently works for D.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Small note: The points, as they are defined, do not yet give three equilateral triangles. I chose some points first and wanted to take care of the geometric centroids first.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a typo: use `{ }` instead of `( )`

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){a}
    \tkzDefPoint(5,1){b}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,4){c}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,-3){d}
    \tkzDefPoint(6,4){e}
    \tkzDefPoint(-1,3){f}
    
    \tkzDrawPolygon(a,b,c)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(a,b,d)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(b,c,e)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(a,c,f)
    
    \tkzInCenter(a,b,c)\tkzGetPoint{D}
    
    \tkzInCenter(a,b,d)\tkzGetPoint{A}% ! { }
    
    \tkzInCenter(b,c,e)\tkzGetPoint{B}%(B)
    
    \tkzInCenter(a,c,f)\tkzGetPoint{C}%(C)
    
    \tkzDrawPoint[red](D)
    \tkzDrawPoint[red](A)
    \tkzDrawPoint[red](B)
    \tkzDrawPoint[red](C)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C) 
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh my god, I feel so stupid. I might as well delete this post, but on the other hand, perhaps others could learn from it. Thank you!

Comment: Lol, everyone's been there. This post is super useful for someone else trying to do something simliar.

Comment: No problem, we all made this kind of mistake every now and then … And yes, it‘s hard to spot.

Comment: @JimYe I've used the following rule for the whole package: if the macro concerns points already created, use `()` if the macro creates points, use `{}`.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, the question is useful, as it has enabled me to improve my package. Like the introduction of the `indirect` parameter to define an equilateral triangle in the indirect direction.
I've also introduced the `check_equilateral` function.

The following code will only work with version 1.40 of `tkz-elements`, which arrives this week.
The advantage of the code is that it generalizes the answer. You can modify the initial triangle without modifying anything else.

Some explanations.

`T.ABC` is the initial triangle. It is an object and among its attributes are the lines (or segments) defined by the vertices. We get_points (      ) the lines with `T.A = T.ABC.bc` which corresponds to the straight line (BC) etc. others lines attributes are `ca` and `ab`.

`T.BCD = T.ABC.bc` : equilateral (indirect) defines an equilateral triangle. The indirect parameter is to obtain the triangle such that (BC,BD)=-60°

A triangle has three vertices represented by the attributes (pa,pb,pc). We obtain the vertices with: `z.D = T.BCD.pc`.

Then we get_points (        ) the centroid point of each triangle.
`check_equilateral` is a test to determine whether the triangle is equilateral.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,tkz-elements,ifthen}
\begin{document}
   
 \begin{tkzelements}
   z.A = point :  new ( 0 , 0 )
   z.B = point :  new ( 5 , 1 ) 
   z.C = point :  new ( 1 , 3 ) 
   T.ABC = triangle  :  new (z.A,z.B,z.C)
   T.BCD = T.ABC.bc : equilateral (indirect)
   T.CAE = T.ABC.ca : equilateral (indirect)
   T.ABF = T.ABC.ab : equilateral (indirect)
   z.D = T.BCD.pc
   z.E = T.CAE.pc
   z.F = T.ABF.pc
   z.G = T.BCD.centroid
   z.H = T.CAE.centroid
   z.I = T.ABF.centroid
   T.GHI = triangle : new (z.G,z.H,z.I)
   bool_GHI = T.GHI : check_equilateral ()
   bool_ABC = T.ABC : check_equilateral ()
\end{tkzelements}
   
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\tkzGetNodes
\tkzDrawPolygons[thick](B,C,D A,C,E A,B,F) 
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I)

\ifthenelse{\equal{\tkzUseLua{bool_GHI}}{false}}{%
\tikzset{col/.style = {green}}}{\tikzset{col/.style = {red}}}
\tkzDrawPolygons[thick,col](G,H,I)

\ifthenelse{\equal{\tkzUseLua{bool_ABC}}{false}}{%
\tikzset{col/.style = {green}}}{\tikzset{col/.style = {red}}}
\tkzDrawPolygons[thick,col](A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]